# i'm trying to make my discord bot to record audio using prism-media as said in the example of @discordjs/voice but i'm getting error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot that records the voice channel

the libraries
`discord.js@13.6.0`, `@discordjs/voice@0.8.0`, `prism-media@2.0.0-alpha.0`, `node-crc@2.0.13`

my imports

```js
const { createWriteStream } = require("node:fs")
const { pipeline } = require("node:stream")

const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { joinVoiceChannel, getVoiceConnection, EndBehaviorType } = require("@discordjs/voice");
const prism = require('prism-media')

const { token } = require("./secrets.json");
```

the part of my code that I think is causing the errors

```js
        if (!newState.selfMute) {
        const reciever = getVoiceConnection(newState.guild.id).receiver;
        const opusStream = reciever.subscribe(newState.id, {
            end: {
                behavior: EndBehaviorType.AfterSilence,
                duration: 100,
            },
        });

        const oggStream = new prism.opus.OggLogicalBitstream(
            {
                opusHead: new prism.opus.OpusHead({
                    channelCount: 2,
                    sampleRate: 48000,
                }),
                pageSizeControl: {
                    maxPackets: 10,
                },
            }
        );
```

The second half is identical to what is shown on the github page of `@discordjs/voice` https://github.com/discordjs/voice/blob/309ac8596cac422cf22e51331869e011c720124c/examples/recorder/src/createListeningStream.ts#L19

the error

```
C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\node-crc\lib\lib.js:12
    return _crc.crc(polyLow, polyHigh, bit, initialLow, initialHigh, finalXorLow, finalXorHigh, reflect, data);
                ^

TypeError: failed to downcast any to number
    at crc (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\node-crc\lib\lib.js:12:17)
    at OggLogicalBitstream.calculateCRC (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\prism-media\dist\ogg\OggLogicalBitstream.js:92:23)
    at OggLogicalBitstream.writePage (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\prism-media\dist\ogg\OggLogicalBitstream.js:150:33)
    at OggLogicalBitstream.writeHeaderPages (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\prism-media\dist\ogg\OggLogicalBitstream.js:74:18)
    at new OggLogicalBitstream (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\prism-media\dist\opus\OggLogicalBitstream.js:16:14)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\index.js:57:27)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\VoiceStateUpdate.js:38:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\source\discord_bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
```

Comment: Can you show us your imports/require statements? Also, what is crc:false?

Comment: imports: const { createWriteStream } = require("node:fs")
const { pipeline } = require("node:stream")

const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { joinVoiceChannel, getVoiceConnection, EndBehaviorType } = require("@discordjs/voice");
const { opus } = require("prism-media");

const { token } = require("./secrets.json");

Comment: crc: false is something i found while searching for solutions but it didn't help and i don't know what it does it was here https://github.com/amishshah/prism-media/issues/86

Comment: What is "prism?" Its not in your imports. Should that constructor actually just be opus.OpusHead(...) or even opus.opus.OpusHead? "Prism" does not exist in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `crc: false` as such

```js
const oggStream = new prism.opus.OggLogicalBitstream(
    {
        opusHead: new prism.opus.OpusHead({
            channelCount: 2,
            sampleRate: 48000,
        }),
        pageSizeControl: {
            maxPackets: 10,
        },
        crc: false
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your imports:

```
const { createWriteStream } = require("node:fs") 
const { pipeline } = require("node:stream") 
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js"); 
const { joinVoiceChannel, getVoiceConnection, EndBehaviorType } = require("@discordjs/voice"); 
const { opus } = require("prism-media");  // THIS IS THE WRONG BIT
const { token } = require("./secrets.json");
```

You are importing `opus` from `prism-media`. You don't have a `prism` variable. Yet you call it here:

```
const oggStream = new prism.opus.OggLogicalBitstream( //WRONG
    {
        opusHead: new prism.opus.OpusHead({ //WRONG
            channelCount: 2,
            sampleRate: 48000,
        }),
        pageSizeControl: {
            maxPackets: 10,
        },
        crc: false
    }
);
```

You didn't import `prism` though, just `prism.opus`. Change your code to:

```
const oggStream = new opus.OggLogicalBitstream(
    {
        opusHead: new opus.OpusHead({
            channelCount: 2,
            sampleRate: 48000,
        }),
        pageSizeControl: {
            maxPackets: 10,
        },
        crc: false
    }
);
```

Or you can change the import, but that may break other existing code.

```
const prism = require("prism-media");          // THIS INSTEAD OF
const { opus } = require("prism-media");  // THIS
```

Comment: Oh i did not realize that. But i'm still getting the errors. i tried `import prism from 'prism-media'` and got `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` i tried `const prism = require("prism-media")` and got the same error as the one i was getting when i started this question `TypeError: prism.opus.OpusHead is not a constructor` and with `const { opus } = require('prism-media')` i changed the `new prism.opus.OpusHead` to `opus.OpusHead` and got the same error `TypeError: opus.OpusHead is not a constructor`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. For the second solution, do 'const prism =' instead of 'import prism from'. I updated my answer above.

Comment: i already tried that. it shows me `TypeError: prism.opus.OpusHead is not a constructor`

Comment: Please update your question to show your current imports. It should work if you've done the above.

Comment: ok i updated my question and no it does not work

Comment: any updates on that? Got the same Problem, tried the solution aswell but nothing changed regarding the error message

Answer (score 0):

Use `prism-media@2.0.0-alpha.0`.

For this:

```sh
npm i prism-media@2.0.0-alpha.0
```

Comment: i did that now i'm getting another error
`Error: Cannot find module 'node-crc'` and when i try to install it with npm it gives me more errors `Error: could not find the \`cargo\` executable.`